# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting, stuck at a "blocks" screen

Tags: boot

Dell Inspiron with AMD A8 processor laptop dual booted with Windows 10.

This is now the second time this has happened. The first time, I just wiped everything out and reinstalled both OS's. I don't want to do this again.

When I try to boot Ubuntu, it sticks at a screen that says the following:

```
/dev/sda6 clean, 268375/23969792 files, 13166276/95854592 blocks
```

One day it's working and booting fine, and the next, I get this. I can boot into Windows just fine, still, but I can't boot into Ubuntu.

results of blkid:

[image: blkid]

contents of fstab:

[image: fstab]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and tried almost everything to resolve this issue. But after 2 days of hassle finally realized that there was no space left on the disk that was causing this issue. You might wanna check space left on your disk before trying any other solutions:

`df -h --total`

Answer (score 1):

## Step #1

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

## Step #2

If step #1 doesn't fix your problem, then do this:

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo blkid`
  - `sudo cat /etc/fstab`
- edit your question to include the output from the two previous commands
- type `reboot`

## Step #3

We need to fix a problem in your `/etc/fstab`...

**update: this particular problem may make it difficult to edit `/etc/fstab` because it'll either timeout in less than 2 minutes, or put extra characters into the file, or just act crazy. If this happens, you'll need to edit this file while booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `mount -o rw,remount /`
  - `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak` **# only need to do this once... the first time**
  - `sudo pico /etc/fstab`
  - use the arrow keys to move around in the file
  - find the line that contains `umask=0077`, and **CAREFULLY** change only `umask=0077` so that it shows as `defaults`, instead of `umask=0077`
  - <kbd>control-o</kbd>, and then the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, will save your edits
  - <kbd>control-x</kbd> will exit the pico editor
  - `reboot`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53487/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-16-04-not-booting-stuck-at-a-blocks-s).