# Ubuntu is not loading any desktop environment

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

I had installed xfce DE in ubuntu 20.04.1 lts. While installing, I had selected lightdm as my default DE. After a week I have uninstalled xfce DE, Then I have not faced any problem. But after power off laptop, when I tried to open it again, it is not loading gnome DE which is available in system. The laptop is showing black screen and loads nothing.[Image of black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/six0U.jpg)
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: do you have any images?

Comment: Yes, wait I am editing my post with images.

Comment: @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne  I have added the image, please check it.

Comment: Can this help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/882361/ubuntu-16-04-not-booting-stuck-at-a-blocks-screen. Also can you boot to recovery mode: Grub-> Advanced -> Recovery ->  Root acces?

Comment: why is it stuck at those words?

Comment: @V.H. I am trying to do this but it is not working for me

Comment: @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne I do not know why is it happenning....

Comment: If you can get to a terminal, try the advanced options at GRUB, you can try reinstalling the desktop. `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @KGIII  If I use live cd, then can I solve this issue?

Comment: @MuhammadAsrafAhmedImon, you should be able to. Look up 'chroot' and that route should work for you - at least to try it.

Comment: @KGIII Last 2 days I am trying to use live cd, but I can not use it. I am not getting any option to boot from live cd. Now what can I do?